# @Output from dynamically created Component in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

In my angular 6 project, I have a dynamically created component like below:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-staff-dash',
    template: `
    <template #tasksContainer></template>
`
})

export class StaffDashComponent implements OnInit {

    componentRef: any;
    factory: any;
    @ViewChild('tasksContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) tasksEntry: ViewContainerRef;


    constructor(
        @Inject(ComponentFactoryResolver) private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.createTasksComponent();
    }


    createTasksComponent(): void {
        this.tasksEntry.clear();
        this.factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TasksComponent);
        this.componentRef = this.tasksEntry.createComponent(this.factory);
    }
}
```

`StaffDashComponent` is the parent and `TasksComponent` is the child. Now I want some data to be passed from `TasksComponent` to `StaffDashComponent` using `@Output`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

For dynamically created child component, You have to subscribe to output event within the parent component.

parent.comp

```
createTasksComponent(): void {
        this.tasksEntry.clear();
        this.factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TasksComponent);
        this.componentRef = this.tasksEntry.createComponent(this.factory);
        //subscribe to child output event
        this.componentRef.instance.outputEvent.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
}
```

child comp

```
@Output() outputEvent : EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>(); 
someFunc() {
      this.outputEvent.emit(true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For angular13+,
you'd better do as this

```
componentRef.instance.delEvent.subscribe(
      value=>this.delOneItem(value)
    )
```

this is for child
@Output()
delEvent: EventEmitter=new EventEmitter();